# Force HTTP for all pages except specific URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have a situation where I need to force every single page in my site to redirect to HTTP except for two specific URLs which need to force redirect to HTTPS.

The two pages that need to redirect to HTTPS pages are:

*/microsoft-moc-on-demand-video-training/moc-registration-page/*

*/courses/register/*

The code I've been using in my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/courses/register/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/microsoft-moc-on-demand-video-training/moc-registration-page/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(/courses/register/|/microsoft-moc-on-demand-video-training/moc-registration-page/)/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working. The entire site does redirect to HTTP (so part of the code works), but those two exceptions (which should redirect to HTTPS) do not do that, they stay as HTTP links.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Just a related question : why don't you redirect everything to https? If you manipulate personnal data or credit card informations, I strongly suggest you to use https on the whole website to avoid mistakes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for `RewriteRule`, there is no initial `/` in the requested path. Therefore, you're trying to match something that isn't present.

You also had an extra `/` at the end of each option in the first capture group, which when combined with the final `/` would require a path such as `/courses/register//`.

The following code should suit your needs:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/courses/register/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/microsoft-moc-on-demand-video-training/moc-registration-page/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(courses/register|microsoft-moc-on-demand-video-training/moc-registration-page)/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```